# Nginx rule to add x-robots-tag header

Tags: nginx

I just moved from apache to nginx and cant fathom this rule.

I want to add this header to all pages that include a query string.

```
add_header X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow";
```

The apache working rule was.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(sortOrder|sortField) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MY_SET_HEADER:1]
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex,nofollow" env=MY_SET_HEADER
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 54):

The next line should be in the `location` block of your nginx config (usually in `/etc/nginx/sites-avalable/`):

```
add_header  X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive";
```

Should be nice to check before and after the modification with an:

```
# service nginx reload
```

Through this online tool: http://headers.cloxy.net

And it should show:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive
```

Comment: I have follow the same steps but "X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow, nosnippet, noarchive" not appear in headers any idea?

Comment: Are quotes located correctly?
Is the nginx service operative? (some times get blocked and need manually restart)

Comment: or do you overwrite the X-Robots-Tag later?